# iOS: Local notification very slow to show up when phone locked

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

We've been developing an iOS application (iOS 9+ only) in Swift. We are using VOIP notifications for certain things then use local notifications to actually show the message to the user.

My problem is that when the phone is locked it can take up to 15 seconds for the local notification to actually get displayed, even though I can see my debug output and the code being ran immediately when I expect it.

This is my code for showing the notification:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertTitle = "Title text.".local
    notification.alertBody = "Body text."
    notification.alertAction = "Action".local
    notification.category = Notification.CallCategory
    notification.soundName = localNotificationSoundName
    notification.userInfo = msg.dictionary()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```

Other than the delay everything works as expected and when the phone is not locked there is no delay and the notification works as expected.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As a clarification this code is being run inside a switch/case that resides in our implementation of PKPushRegistryDelegate. Specifically within this function:

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!)
```

Additionally it is worth noting that this not happen on every device. We have one iPhone 6s test device where it happens every time, regardless of how many times we reboot the device, reinstall the app or even upgrade iOS to a newer version. We have a few other test devices where it doesnt happen.

Comment: I don't know for sure (hence it's a comment, not an answer), but I guess iOS doesn't prioritise notifications when it's in sleep mode. Or it only fetches the notifications once every few seconds, to maximise battery power. That would explain the notifications working as expected when the phone is unlocked.

Comment: That's not it, since the application is using VOIP notifications and is running on the background.

This issue keeps getting stranger though because it is not happening on all of our test devices. It can be repeated on a few devices but not all of them. Rebooting the device, installing/uninstalling or even updating iOS version has no affect on it either.

Comment: do check facebook messenger app once. I guess it uses local notification for calls. Check if its delay by 10-15 sec or not ! I do have experienced local notification being not fired at exact time so maybe its a system design to give less prioritise to local notification for exact time.

Comment: Where is this code running? Can you post the full function?

Comment: This code is being run within our PKPushRegistryDelegate implementation, specifically in this function: func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!)

Comment: Did you find out what was the reason? We're in the same situation: VoIP app with VoIP pushes written in Swift. Local notifications are also displayed with a big delay. And this issue reproduces only on one device - iPhone 6S.

Comment: The exact same thing happens to my on my iPhone 6S with WhatsApp notifications, which AFAIK uses the same trick for displaying push notifications. It's quite annoying because with WhatsApp web enabled I can often see the notification on the browser and only 10 secs or so later it pops up on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Read this from Apple doc -

> Prioritize Remote Notification Delivery
>
> Remote notifications provided by your server to the Apple Notification
>   Service include a variety of elements, including payload data, an
>   expiration date, a priority, and more. Remote notifications support
>   two levels of push priority. One delivers the notification
>   immediately. The other delays delivery of the notification until an
>   energy-efficient time. Unless a notification truly requires an
>   immediate delivery, use the deferred delivery method.

[NotificationBestPractices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/NotificationBestPractices.html)

1. I know your problem is for slow `local notification` but still make sure you have Prioritize remote notification.
2. I have experienced while testing that app has certain delay when using local notifications. Maybe that is how system is designed and not necessarily a flaw. For VOIP case I still think you should have used push notification to notify the call (Maybe you have some internal calculation before making notification). But do check out Facebook messenger app, it looks like it does mix match push / local notification to notify user for calls. Try to observe the delay if any.
3. Make another simple app which shows Local Notification for same code as above and observe if it too has some delay. For this test don't use remote notification to fire the Local Notification, just test after app launch or something like that. This is to make sure if system is delaying certain apps notification for case immediately after push notification ?

Comment: Pretty good observations, I'll look into creating a test app just for testing the local notification.

We are using VOIP notifications because we've bee under the impression that they get delivered the fastest. And in our case there is a person on the other end waiting for the other person to answer / decline so every second matters.

Comment: @VilleRinne Did you get any solutions for this? We are also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try Settings->General->Reset-> Reset Network Settings

Answer (score 0):

I found the possible cause - iPhone was paired with Apple Watch. In spite of the fact that the watch was in the drawer and turned off, iPhone was trying to route the notifications to it. After we had unpaired iPhone from watch and wait for a while, everything became normal.